# Ignore test failure

Tags: yaml, travis-ci, github-actions

I seek to ensure a test passes no matter what:

```
 - conda run pytest
```

How can this be accomplished? I have done it with "or" syntax previously, as in

```
 - 1 || conda run pytest
```

but don't recall how exactly.

Comment: YAML syntax aside, that's _not_ how you suppress a non-zero exit with `||`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've seen it done before.

Comment: Assuming this is in a GitHub Actions workflow you should post a full workflow definition that reproduces the problem.

Comment: In bash, you can add `|| true` at the end of the command line to ignore the eventual errors (e.g: `<command> || true`). Basically, the runner will always considerer the command line has been executed successfully. Is it what you want to achieve? (Otherwise, I agree with riQQ, give us more context to help you please).

Comment: @GuiFalourd Perfect - I'll accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `bash` shell, you can add `|| true` at the end of the command line to ignore the eventual errors:

`<command> || true`

Basically, the runner will always consider the command line has been executed successfully.

*Just note that it won't stop the workflow run (or make the workflow fail) as well if the command return an error.*